# How to deploy SpringBoot Application on Weblogic application server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a SpringBoot Application. 
I want to deploy this on my local Server (Weblogic 12c).
When I try to deploy the war, I get this error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Invalid source type class my.company.MySpringBootApplication

This is my incriminated class:

```
package my.company;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(this);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. Try to replace with `application.sources(MySpringBootApplication.class)`

Comment: thank you very much!
I have solved with your suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of substituting this line:

```
package my.company;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;


@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MySpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer  {

    @Value("${flag.status}")
    private String flagStatus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<MySpringBootApplication > applicationClass = MySpringBootApplication .class;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is that flag.status coming from a yml file. My issue is that weblogic is not finding the yml file entries. The yml file is under src/main/resources. And in dispatcher-servlet.xml I do have a mapping to the resources folder. --Thanks.